# Display materialize icons next to text?

Tags: css, material-design, materialize

I can't seem to make it work, the materialize icon is either on the most left or right part.

Here's a sample

```
<a href="#">
    Some text <i class="material-icons">warning</i>
</a>
```

In default, it's on the most left side of the text, but if I add "right" on `<i>`'s class. I'll be on the most right part with whitespaces. What I want is it to be next to the text (right)

Comment: It may not be whitespaces. `material-icons` class may have `margin-left` or `padding-left` assigned to it.

Comment: working fine for me https://fiddle.jshell.net/un2trf2m/ ....what are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove warning outside of the `<i></i>` tag and then try the following. Hope, it works for you.

`Some text <span><i class="material-icons"></i></span> warning`